# Use IP address as the Origin when Creating a Cloudfront Distribution?

Tags: ip-address, amazon-cloudfront

I am setting up a Cloudfront Distribution.

In this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/, it said "you can simply type the DNS name or IP address if it not listed." as the origin. However, when I input an IP address as the origin, I get an error indicating "IP cannot be used as the origin name". Why?

Comment: Have you asked AWS support?

Comment: @Steve, It seems that they only provide paid support. So I have on their community but get no response https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=345170

Answer (score 5):

There are two reasons that I wouldn't expect a CDN to allow you to specify the origin server by IP address:

- Most websites are not accessible via IP address.  Most hosting is on shared hosting where every IP address has many websites.   Even if you have dedicated hosting with your own IP address, you would usually want to be able to serve several of your own domain names from your servers.
- Security certificates for IP addresses are are uncommon and expensive.  (Free LetsEncrypt certificates are not available for IP addresses, for example.)   Most users aren't going to be able to enable HTTPS to the origin server by IP address.

Because there are few users that would have a dedicated IP address just for one domain and be willing to pay for the the certificate for it, it would make sense to simplify and only allow host names and not IP address.  It would be less headache for them not to have to support IP addresses and prevent problems of users trying to use an IP address that isn't likely to work.

If you do have an IP address just for your site, the workaround is to create a host name for it.   For example you could create the subdomain `origin.example.com` on your domain `example.com`.  The `origin` subdomain would point to the IP address of your server.

Comment: Thank you. But using subdomain origin.example.com will cause problems in WordPress. If using origin.example.com, what should be set for WordPress SiteURL and HomeURL? If setting to origin.example.com, then WordPress will take origin.example.com as the canonical URL, which is obviously undesired. However, if set to www.example.com, then the site will not be loaded properly.

Comment: @alancc Leave your WordPress site alone. It would still respond to requests for `example.com` but whitelist the `Host` header in cloudfront so that `www.example.com` gets passed to wordpress.    See on StackOverflow: [Any way to set up AWS Cloudfront to point to static IP address (WP hosted on GoDaddy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55681184/any-way-to-set-up-aws-cloudfront-to-point-to-static-ip-address-wp-hosted-on-god)

Comment: Sorry but I can still not understand as how to setup my WordPress on the origin. Which SiteURL and HomeURL should I use? I cannot leave it alone as it is the CMS on the origin. Thank you.